# Kivy Button doesn't work as axpected when placed on a Canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm building an application which has some buttons which send (and receive) MQTT messages over the network. I've created two GridLayouts and placed some buttons on them which work as I expected. Then I've created a canvas with the contours of a ship drawn on it. I want to place buttons on the positions of the navigation lights so I can control the navigation lights with these buttons. For testing purpose I've added one button to the canvas on a fixed position. I can not push the button using the touchscreen (the buttons on the GridLayout work with the touchscreen). I can push the button with the mouse but then no event is fired and no MQTT message is send. Can I add a Button directly to the Canvas like I did or do I need to add another layer?
If you want to test this you can replace the MQTTToggleButton with a normal ToggleButton.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import Ellipse, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

from gui.widget.mqtttogglebutton import MQTTToggleButton
from library.mqtt.client import Client


class ButtonScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, client, buttons, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(cols=4, spacing=10, padding=10, **kwargs)
        self._client = client

        for topic, text in buttons.items():
            button = MQTTToggleButton(text=text, font_size='10dp', client=client, topic=topic)
            button.bind(state=self.button_callback)
            self.add_widget(button)

    def button_callback(self, button, state):
        if isinstance(button, MQTTToggleButton):
            self._client.publish(button.topic, button.payload)


class NavigationLightsScreen(Widget):
    def __init__(self, ship_size, client, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._ship_size = ship_size
        self._client = client
        self.bind(pos=self.draw_ship)
        self.bind(size=self.draw_ship)
        self.draw_ship()

    def draw_ship(self, *args):
        self.canvas.clear()
        with self.canvas:
            Color(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1)
            width = int(self._ship_size[1] * self.calc_pixels_per_meter())
            length_stern = int(width * 1.2 / 2)
            length_bow = int(width * 2.3 / 2)
            # stern
            Ellipse(pos=(self.x, self.y + (self.height - width) / 2), size=(length_stern * 2, width), angle_start=180,
                    angle_end=360)
            # bow
            Ellipse(pos=(self.x + self.width - length_bow * 2, self.y + (self.height - width) / 2),
                    size=(length_bow * 2, width), angle_start=0, angle_end=180)
            # midship
            Rectangle(pos=(self.x + length_stern, self.y + (self.height - width) / 2),
                      size=(self.width - length_bow - length_stern, width))

        self.add_widget(MQTTToggleButton(text='Stern light', font_size='10dp', client=self._client, topic='relay/0',
                                         pos=(100, 100)))

    def calc_pixels_per_meter(self):
        pixels_per_meter_length = self.width / self._ship_size[0]
        pixels_per_meter_width = self.height / self._ship_size[1]
        return min(pixels_per_meter_length, pixels_per_meter_width)


class ShipControlCarousel(Carousel):
    def __init__(self, client, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.add_widget(NavigationLightsScreen(ship_size=(28.01, 5.70), client=client))

        buttons = OrderedDict()
        buttons['relay/0'] = 'Generator machinekamer'
        buttons['relay/1'] = 'Generator achterpiek'
        buttons['relay/2'] = 'Startluchtcompressor'
        buttons['relay/3'] = 'Ruitenwissers'
        buttons['relay/4'] = 'Navigatie computer'
        buttons['relay/5'] = 'Radar'
        buttons['relay/6'] = 'Satalietkompas'
        self.add_widget(ButtonScreen(client=client, buttons=buttons))

        buttons = OrderedDict()
        buttons['relay/0'] = 'Generator machinekamer'
        buttons['relay/1'] = 'Generator achterpiek'
        buttons['relay/7'] = 'Verlichting gangboord'
        buttons['relay/8'] = 'Verlichting dekhut stuurboord'
        buttons['relay/9'] = 'Verlichting dekhut bakboord'
        self.add_widget(ButtonScreen(client=client, buttons=buttons))


class Application(App):
    def build(self):
        return ShipControlCarousel(client=Client(client_id='gui', host='127.0.0.1'), direction='right')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Window.fullscreen = True
    Application().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about this, I overlooked the line

```
button.bind(state=self.button_callback)
```

for the other buttons.

I now moved this code and the callback to the MQTTToggleButton class so I don't need to call it each time I create a button. It works as expected now.